# JSR223 Assertion : Passing a custom key to JsonOutput.toJson()

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

I am doing a validation using the following code:

```js
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String sourceTargetPassJson = "{\"Apple\":[\"Apple\",\"Orange\",\"Kiwi\",\"Avocado\"],\"Orange\":[\"Orange\",\"Kiwi\",\"Avocado\"]}";

def sourceVar = vars.get("source_type");
def targetVar = vars.get("target_type");

log.info("Source :" + sourceVar + ", Target :" + targetVar + ".");

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(sourceTargetPassJson);

def json = JsonOutput.toJson(response.sourceVar);

log.info("Response: " + json);

vars.put("json", json);
```

Here, the `def json = JsonOutput.toJson(response.sourceVar);` is failing because there is no key called `sourceVar`, which is obtained based on the Jmeter variable `source_type`. Given that the above assertion is in a loop controller, I want to validate based on the `source_type` obtained on each iteration.

Example :

Iteration 1, `sourceVar = "Apple"`, `json` should have `["Apple","Orange","Kiwi","Avocado"]`.
Iteration 2, `sourceVar = "Orange"`, `json` should have `["Orange","Kiwi","Avocado"]`.

How do I obtain the value for the variable `json` here based on the custom value of `sourceVar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply resolved by the following change :

```js
String json = response[sourceVar];
```

So, if the `sourceVar` is `"Apple"`, the value of `json` obtained is `[Apple,Orange,Kiwi,Avocado]`